# Why is github highlighting "test" as blue in markdown?

Tags: github, markdown

See this gist: https://gist.github.com/mehagar/10e22e1696aeef389f744923ec092aba

I have it marked as `console`.

But why would test be highlighted blue? I don't want it to be highlighted blue.

Comment: Why don’t you like blue? It’s a lovely colour. The sky, the sea... I’d personally be appreciative of the blue.

Comment: `test` is a built-in command shell command; I don't think the syntax highlighter considers the context in which it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `bash` instead of `console` – I’m not sure `console` is a thing?

Edit: Yup turns out `console` [is a thing](https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/languages.yml#L4356). Looks like blue it is!

Comment: Nope, still blue.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use `PowerShell`, which does not do the blue highlighting.